# How to Reduce Size of Image in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, bitmap, writeablebitmap

I am trying to port my app in windows phone . i have to upload an image on server So it is in small Size For uploading i have done this thing in Widows Successfully but problem is when i failed in it .. here is my code for windows App

```
public void CompressImage(int i, int j)
        {
            bmp1.SetPixel(j, i, Color.FromArgb(bmp.GetPixel(j, i).R, bmp.GetPixel(j, i).G, bmp.GetPixel(j, i).B));   
        }



        private void bLoadImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(file.FileName);
            }
        }


        private void bCompression_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
            bmp1 = new Bitmap(bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            for (int i = 1; i < bmp.Height; i++)
                for (int j = 1; j < bmp.Width; j++)
                {
                    CompressImage(i, j);
                }
            pictureBox2.Image = bmp1;
            bmp1.Save("Picture.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
```

After Searching on google i found out that windows Phone does not support Bitmap .. any idea  how i can do the same thing in windows phone or any other alternative for doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use WriteablBitmap to reduce size of image. WriteablBitmap has number of methods for images in windows phone [Here](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) is more about writeablebitmapex.

Comment: yes i have seen this link before when i am create an object of WriteableBitmap i see very few method in it ..

Comment: @MashhoodAdeeb WriteableBitmapExtensions has Resize method that is helpful for you.

Comment: this is the error i am getting while adding its reference to my project **A reference to higher version or in compatibility assembly cannot be added** @Jaihind  WriteableBitmapExtensions

Comment: @MashhoodAdeeb use 'Install-Package WriteableBitmapEx' nuget command to add refrence.

Answer (score 0):

When you are taking picture you can choose the resolution with which the picture will be taken. This can be done by

```
PhotoCamera cam;
```

After camera initizalition.

Following code when image is capturing (in the method that captures the image)

```
IEnumerable<Size> resList = cam.AvailableResolutions;

Size res;
if (resList.Count() > 0)
{
    res = resList.ElementAt<Size>(0);
    cam.Resolution = res;

 }
```

This sample chooses the first resolution

Comment: Sorry i did not understand your answer should i have to set the properties of camera before it capture an image .... Or should it reduce the size of image ??

Comment: Yes, you can set the camera properties after camera initialization(Resolution in this case) to capture the image in small resolution which will automatically give you image of smaller size

Answer (score 0):

Try to load your original image to [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object, then you can use [SaveJpeg()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) extension method from `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace, to save new image with reduced size. For example :

```
.......
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImageObject);
wb.SaveJpeg(stream, 120, 160, 0, 100);
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It worked for me. It reduced my 9.70MB file into 270KB.

```
WriteableBitmap cameraCapturedImage = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(e.ChosenPhoto, 1024, 1024);

using (IsolatedStorageFileStream myFileStream = myStore.CreateFile(fileName))
{
  System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(cameraCapturedImage, myFileStream, cameraCapturedImage.PixelWidth, cameraCapturedImage.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
  myFileStream.Close();
}
```

N.B: fileName is the name of file to save size reduced image.